# IIS Redirect To SubFolder

Tags: iis-7, redirect, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect a url to a subfolder, for example:

http://localhost/test is what the user will input, but I want that to redirect to http://localhost/test/public

I can't find any resource on the web, and most resources I found is on Apache which doesn't help.

Thanks.

PlayKid

Comment: I am using version 7, and I have already installed the URL rewrite module, but I am not sure how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config file in the Root of the site you would put something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="test">
        <system.webServer>
            <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="test/public" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```